getting empty list while trying to get reviews from woo rest Api
I am trying to use https://<url>/wp-json/wc/v3/products/reviews to get all reviews in Postman which must work fine based on the document but I get an empty list . I am using basic Auth and note that I have no problem in getting products and orders
also when I change the request body to https://<url>/wp-json/wc/v3/products/reviews/<id of one product> I face the below response
"code": "woocommerce_rest_cannot_view",
    "message": "Unfortunately, you cannot view the resources.",
    "data": {
        "status": 403
    }

I have no Idea what the problem is

Status 403 suggests an issue with your permissions. Does your user setup in the basic authentication have permission to access the reviews?

@oscar another person has created this access point and gave it to me can you please tell me how he can give access of reviews to this end point that I have so I can notify him and ask for the change
